# duplicate result on change event in forms_for block

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails.

I have nested form.

```
<div id="items">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :items do |i| %>
      <%= render 'item_fields', :f => i %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association '+ produk', f, :items %>
  </div>
</div>
```

item_fields:

```
<%= f.select :product_id, Product.all.collect {|p| [p.name, p.id, {'data-unit_cost'=>p.sell_price }]}, { class: 'product-select'} %>
<%= f.input :qty %>
<%= f.input :unit_cost%>
<%= f.input :discount %>
<%= f.number_field :subtotal %>
```

script:

```
$(".product-select").change ->
  unit_cost = $('.product-select :selected').data('unit_cost') or 0
```

The idea is whenever product_id is selected, it will set the value of unit_cost.
The thing is, it works only for the first row of the nested form, the second one and next, the value will be duplicated of the first row.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your full form of items, as the id of `:unit_cost` may be different with different `form_for`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your _item_fields:

```
<%= f.select :product_id, Product.all.collect {|p| [p.name, p.id, {'data-unit_cost'=>p.sell_price }]}, {}, { class: 'product-select'} %>
```

add an empty hash before the `class: 'product-select'` as the `:html_option` is the last(4th) parameter of f.select and the third is called `:option`.

```
<%= f.input :unit_cost%> #Add an id for selecting element
```

And also edit your script:

```
$(document).ready ->
  unit_cost = $('#items_items_unit_cost')
  unit_cost.val($('.product-select :selected').data('unit_cost'))
  $(".product-select").change ->
    unit_cost.val($('.product-select :selected').data('unit_cost'))
```

I'm using rails4 and it seems that there aren't `simple_fields_for` or `f.input`. So I use `fields_for` and `f.text_field` instead. This works on my test code but I'm not sure whether it could work for you. Just try it:)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.
I am using SimpleForm gem, so it becomes simple_fields_for.
I got error "wrong number of arguments (5 for 2..4)" if I add () on select.
I have added id to unit_cost but it the value of unit_cost still duplicating from first unit_cost.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. It shouldn't be `()`, but `{}`. I have corrected it and please try again:)

Comment: And after I bundled the `simple_form` gem I found that it applies a default _id_ to `:unit_cost`. So the script is also changed, just have a try.

Comment: It still the same.
FYI, I am using Cocoon gem also for nested form.
Meanwhile I am going to replicate this situation without any gems. Hopefully it will work. :)